# How to truncate and load data in RDS (SQL Server) using Lambda function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sql-insert

I need to load data into RDS (SQL Server) after deleting the table contents which was previously loaded. That's because I don't want to append the table contents. I would like to achieve this using a Lambda function.

This is my sample Lambda function script:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
# insert data from csv file into dataframe(df).
server = 'yourservername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'username' 
password = 'yourpassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I tried to execute the below before "`insert`" command

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
cursor.execute("truncate table HumanResources.DepartmentTest")
```

Unfortunately it didn't work properly. Although my table was truncated but inserted only one row. Not sure why!

Can someone tell me why just one row got loaded? I have more than 50k rows in my csv file which I am trying to load via S3 bucket. If I run my `cursor.execute` separately it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It did what you told it to do - truncate the table before inserting each row, so only the last row survived.

Comment: It did what I told it to do.. but its wrong. Thats not what I am after. To achieve that, I need to remove  cursor command for truncate from "for index, row in df.iterrows():"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to achieve what I was trying earlier. To load data after truncate old table contents, I need to remove `cursor.execute("truncate table HumanResources.DepartmentTest")` from `"for index, row in df.iterrows():"` and place it under;

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("truncate table HumanResources.DepartmentTest")
```